# How to structure a database in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an application related to pets, so I am in confusing with create the structure of database...

For example I have the below categories:

1. Pets
2. Pets accessories
3. Pets food

for categories each one have a name and an image

and for each category have sub categories like the below one for example I'll call it as  products:

```
 1. image: ""
    name: Hulk
    type: Pets
    age: 2
    price: 200

 2. image: ""
    name: bowl
    type: Pets accessories
    price: 20

 3. image: ""
    name: Gosera Cat
    type: Pets food
    price: 15
```

I am sorry if it is basic question or something, but I just want to know what is the best way to create a database structure in fire store like the previous one...

#Edited
I tired to create the categories something the below image:

[image]

[image]

any suggestions or advice?

Comment: This question is too broad to succinctly answer. If you're struggling with a specific use-case, we can probably help better. For more general data modeling advice, I recommend [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) or Jeff Delaney's excellent material on fireship.io.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for your support :), I am actually got what I need from this play list  :)

Comment: It's a series, so just start with the first episode - and continue until you think you understand enough to get started on your own.